# How is it possible to evaluate sum from 1 to inf of $e^{-n}\cdot(n-(n+1)e^{-1})$

Tags: calculus

How can I evaluate this sum using only analytical methods :

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:e^{-n}\cdot \left(n-\left(n+1\right)\cdot e^{-1}\right)$

I cannot see any possible manipulation to solve it, what can i do?

Comment: Give geometric series a try. Differentiate both the sum function and the series term by term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the exponential through you obtain
$$
n\mathrm{e}^{-n} - (n+1)\mathrm{e}^{-(n+1)}
$$
This is a telescope series. 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n - a_{n+1} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $I(\alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\alpha n}=\frac{1}{e^\alpha-1}$ (it is a geometric series). Then note that your sum
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:e^{-n}\cdot \left(n-\left(n+1\right)\cdot e^{-1}\right)=-I'(1)+e^{-1}I'(1)-e^{-1}I(1).
$$

Answer (score 0):

prove by induction that $$\sum_{n=1}^ke^{-n}(n-(n+1)e^{-1})=e^{-1-k}(-1+e^k-k)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}\left(n-\frac{n+1}e\right)=\frac{e-1}e\sum_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n-1}$$
The second series is a geometric series which can be evaluated to give $\dfrac1{e^2-e}$.
 The first can be written as $$\frac1e+\frac1{e^2}+\frac1{e^2}+\frac1{e^3}+\frac1{e^3}+\frac1{e^3}+\frac1{e^4}+\frac1{e^4}+\frac1{e^4}+\frac1{e^4}+\cdots\\=\left(\frac1{e^1}+\frac1{e^2}+\frac1{e^3}+\frac1{e^4}+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac1{e^2}+\frac1{e^3}+\frac1{e^4}+\cdots\right)+\cdots\\=(e^{-1}+e^{-2}+e^{-3}+\cdots)\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n}$$
which can also be evaluated. This gives $$\frac{1}{e-1}\cdot\frac e{e-1}$$
This gives the end result $$\frac {1}{e-1}-\frac1e\frac1{e-1}=\frac{e-1}{e}\cdot\frac1{e-1}=\frac1e$$